# using sed to replace string using info from matched string

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression

I have strings in a text file with certain formats. I want to replace the word part of the string but keep the numeric identifier. For example, I have strings like `L2_name1`, `L12_name6` but many of the names have similar identifiers: name1 = JohnMSmith, name6 = JohnMSmithinson.

I would like to use something like `sed 's/L2_name1/L2_new_name/g' file.csv` but using regex so something like

`sed -E 's/L[0-9]{1,2}_name1/{same leading monicker found in the matching part}_new_name/g' file.csv`

Comment: You should read about *capture groups*, this answer already explains how to use them. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/263675/31760

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You remember things by parenthesizing what you want to remember in the match part of the command and you recall the remembered things using `\N` with some number N to replace it with what the Nth set of parens in the matching part remembered:

```
sed -E 's/(L[0-9]{1,2})_name([0-9]+)/\1_new_name\2/g' file.csv
```

See the [sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#ERE-syntax) for the full details.

EDIT: I should point out that you are allowed to use various special chars  like `()[]{}+` without escaping them because you have specified `-E` i.e. extended regular expressions. Again the manual provides full details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\0` for referring to the matched string.

```
echo "test string this is a test string" | sed -E 's/test string(.+?)test string/\0 success/'
```

Look up the topic capture-groups in regex for more info.

Comment: How does this answer the question? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.